# Dividing numpy 2d array into equal sections

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 30*30px image and I converted it to a NumPy array. Now I want to divide this 30*30 image into 9 equal pieces (imagine a tic-tak-toe game). I wrote the code below for that purpose but the problem with my code is that it has two nested loops and in python, that means a straight ticket to lower-performance town (specially for large number of datas). So is there a better way of doing this using NumPy and Numpy indexing?

```
#Factor is saing that the image should be divided into 9 sections 3*3 = 9 (kinda like 3 rows 3 columns)
def section(img , factor = 3):
    secs = []

    #This basicaly tests if the image can actually get divided into equal sections
    if (img.shape[0] % factor != 0):
        return False

    #number of pixel in each row and column of the sections
    pix_num = int(img.shape[0] / factor)

    ptr_x_a = 0
    ptr_x_b = pix_num -1


    for i in range(factor):

        ptr_y_a = 0
        ptr_y_b = pix_num - 1
        
        for j in range(factor):

            secs.append( img[ptr_x_a :ptr_x_b , ptr_y_a : ptr_y_b] )
            ptr_y_a += pix_num
            ptr_y_b += pix_num
    
        ptr_x_a += pix_num
        ptr_x_b += pix_num
    
    return np.array(secs , dtype = "int16"‍‍‍‍‍‍‍)
```

P.S: Don't mind reading the whole code, just know that it uses pointers to select different areas of the image.

P.S2: See the image below to get an idea of what's happening. It is  a 6*6 image divided into 9 pieces (`factor = 3`)
[image]

Comment: Can you provide sample input and output?

Comment: There are no pointers in python. You are using simple indexing via slices.

Comment: @AMC I updated the question and added an image to it.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I didn't mean pointers as to the Programming definition of pointers like in C and C++. I meant it as a property that points to different elements of the list.

Comment: @ARK1375. I got that part. You used them correctly, but terminology is important too, since that's how we communicate with others. If you search for pointers online, you won't find much. If you search for slices and indices, you will.

Comment: The thing that's missing in the image is what order you want the chunks in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an array of shape `(K * M, K * N)`, you can transform it into something of shape `(K * K, M, N)` using `reshape` and `transpose`. For example, if you have `K = M = N = 3`, you want to transform

```
>>> a = np.arange(81).reshape(9, 9)
```

into

```
[[[ 0,  1,  2],
  [ 9, 10, 11],
  [18, 19, 20]],
 [[ 3,  4,  5],
  [12, 13, 14],
  [21, 22, 23]],
 [[ 6,  7,  8],
  [15, 16, 17],
  [24, 25, 26]],
 ...
 ]]]
```

The idea is that you need to get the elements lined up in memory in the order shown here (i.e. `0, 1, 2, 9, 10, 11, 18, ...`). You can do this by adding the appropriate auxiliary dimensions and transposing:

```
b = a.reshape(K, M, K, N)
c = b.transpose(0, 2, 1, 3)
d = c.reahape(-1, M, N)
```

As a one-liner:

```
a.reshape(K, M, K, N).transpose(0, 2 1, 3).reshape(-1, M, N)
```

The order of the transpose determines the order of the blocks. The first two dimensions, `0, 2`, represent the fact that your inner loop iterates the columns faster than the rows. If you wanted to arrange the blocks by column (iterate the rows faster), you could do

```
c = b.transpose(2, 0, 1, 3)
```

Reshaping does not change the memory layout of the elements, but transposing copies data if necessary.

In your particular example, `K = 3` and `M = N = 10`. The code above does not change in any way besides that.

As an aside, your loops can be improved by making the ranges directly over the indices you want rather auxiliary quantities, as well as pre-allocating the output:

```
result = np.zeros(factor * factor, pix_num, pix_num)
n = 0
for r in range(0, img.shape[0], pix_num):
    for c in range(0, img.shape[1], pix_num):
         result[n, :, :] = img[r:r + pix_num, c:c + pix_num]
         n += 1
```

Comment: It worked like a charm, but I don't understand the logic behind ```transpose```. I mean I can understand it for 2d arrays but I'm struggling in higher dimensions. Can you explain it to me a little bit?

Comment: @ARK1375. Sure. Transpose changes the order in which you index the dimensions. As such, it alters memory layout (if you keep "C" order). So let's say some array `a` has shape `(3, 4, 5, 6)`, and element at `a[2, 0, 1, 4]` is `17`. If you do `b = a.transpose(2, 1, 3, 0)`, `b.shape` will be `(5, 4, 6, 3)`, and the `17` will move to index `b[1, 0, 4, 2]`. Spend some time playing with it and you'll get it. I still don't find it entirely intuitive myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = np.arange(36)
a.resize(6, 6)
print(a)
 
b = list(map(lambda x: np.array_split(x, 3, axis=1), np.array_split(a, 3, axis=0)))
print(np.array(b).reshape(9,2,2))

[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 15 16 17]
 [18 19 20 21 22 23]
 [24 25 26 27 28 29]
 [30 31 32 33 34 35]]

[[[ 0  1]
  [ 6  7]]

 [[ 2  3]
  [ 8  9]]

 [[ 4  5]
  [10 11]]

 [[12 13]
  [18 19]]

 [[14 15]
  [20 21]]

 [[16 17]
  [22 23]]

 [[24 25]
  [30 31]]

 [[26 27]
  [32 33]]

 [[28 29]
  [34 35]]]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this to get one section:

```
sec = img[:10]
sec = list(zip(*sec))[:10]
sec = list(zip(*sec))
```

This will pick out the first 10x10 section.

Comment: This does not answer the question